# Add Jira task server to IntelliJ using saml authentication

Tags: intellij-idea, jira, saml

I m trying to add a Jira task server to intelliJ but my Jira server is using Saml authentication, there is a way to configure it ?

[image]

Comment: Please vote for the related request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189531

Answer (score 0):

I've just meet this problem. I've found a solution working for me:

1. Open your JIRA profile and select **API Token Authentication**;
2. Push button **New API Token**;
3. Use the generated token instead of your domain password in the IntelliJ Tasks plugin configuration form. Username is your company domain username;

Hope been helpful.

Comment: This is not possible in Jira Server - at least not for the instance i see (v8.5.8).